# Python recursive function returns result for one input, but None for another

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I'm trying to calculate the  modulo  (fibonacci modulo m) using these two functions. The first input returns the result whereas the second input returns *None*. I'm really confused as to what's wrong with this:

```
def get_period(n,m):
    # calculate period of m using fibonacci series
    modular_list=[]
    for idx,element in enumerate(fib_series(n)[0]):
        modular_list.append(element%m)
        for i in range(len(modular_list)-1):
            if modular_list[i]==0 and modular_list[i+1]==1:
                if i>1:
                    period = idx-1
                    modular_list_period = modular_list[:-2]
                    return(period, modular_list_period)
                else:
                    continue

def fib_series(n):
    lst = [0,1]
    for i in range(n):
        if n>=1:
            lst.append(lst[-1]+lst[-2])
        else:
            return 0
    return lst[:-1], lst[-2]

print(get_period(2015,3)) # returns -> (8, [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1])
print(get_period(239,1000)) # returns -> None
```

Comment: When you see this happen, and you don't have a `return None` somewhere, it means your function is finishing without an explicit `return` (all the loops are ending and you've never satisfied the `if` condition where you'd return).

Comment: It is not happening because you're executing it secondly; but since it is executing in the way that you defined it. Iterate with it and you'll find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You have logical error in your code. You `get_period` function completes its execution without returning any value for the second input. That's why its printing default return value `None`. Look at this updated code:

```
def get_period(n,m):
    # calculate period of m using fibonacci series
    modular_list=[]
    for idx,element in enumerate(fib_series(n)[0]):
        modular_list.append(element%m)
        for i in range(len(modular_list)-1):
            if modular_list[i]==0 and modular_list[i+1]==1:
                if i>1:
                    period = idx-1
                    modular_list_period = modular_list[:-2]
                    return(period, modular_list_period) #for the second command this return is not getting executed,try to check value of i and len(modular_list)
                else:
                    continue
    return  modular_list  #updated return statement. previous loop doesn't returns the value the return from here
def fib_series(n):
    lst = [0,1]
    for i in range(n):
        if n>=1:
            lst.append(lst[-1]+lst[-2])
        else:
            return 0

    return lst[:-1], lst[-2]

print(get_period(2015,3)) # returns -> (8, [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1])
print(get_period(239,1000))
```

Comment: Please explain what the error is and what you did to fix it in words. SO is a site not for fixing OP's immediate needs as much as for helping future visitors with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code and also per the chart on [this page](http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/fibonacci/fiblist.htm), the period is 1500. You are getting `None` returned because you did not set `n` high enough. Replace `239` with an integer greater than 1500 and you will see the desired output (which is too voluminous to paste in here).

Try, for example,

`print(get_period(2390,1000))`

instead.

Answer (score 0):

print(get_period(100,44))#you have to pass less value for m,
print(get_period(239,90))#like this,m value should less than n.

Comment: No, that is not the case at all. The period of 1000 is 1500 but the period of 1001 is 560. Running `print(get_period(561,1001))` will produce output.